# Grafana integration with SAP HANA

Tags: grafana, monitoring, hana

I would like to monitoring my SAP HANA database with something like Grafana, but I can't realize a way to integrate Grafana with SAP HANA, there are any way to use Granafa with HANA database? Somebody knows a Grafana like application that I could use instead?

Comment: How do you plan to query monitoring views from HANA DB, e.g. M_HOST_RESOURCE_UTILIZATION?

Comment: What I really need is to get up to date if my network link with VPN [where hanna was installed] still up or I got disconnected, memory and CPU usages and is a better to have something to see the number of request to the server and network usage as well

Comment: You don't need HANA for that. I thought for some reason that you wanted to visualize internal HANA db statistics. You can use collectd daemon to monitor cpu, memory, disk and network on the host where the database is installed.

Comment: You mean I could do that using InfluxDB or Graphite? Do you have any reference link?

Comment: Link to collectd daemon https://collectd.org/ to monitor host utilization. It will monitor host metrics. The daemon supports a range of write plugins for sending data to different storage backends.

Comment: Thank you, I believe this will solve my concerns! Could you answer this question so I can check as solved?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I recommend using collectd daemon to monitor host metrics on the server running the database. The daemon supports multiple storage backends using so called `write` plugins: https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Table_of_Plugins